Has any philosopher written about how our reasoning relies on subtly incompatible assumptions depending on the kind of question we are asking?
I would like to know whether the following idea has already been formalized by some philosopher:
When we reason about questions for which we assume there is an objective or true answer, we rely epistemically on various basic notions; for example, material entities, causes, possibility and impossibility, probability, qualia, freedom and agency, notions of morality (good/bad, ought/shouldn’t), etc.
Depending on the kind of question we are trying to answer, we use a different mix of these notions.
Some examples of the types of question (maybe I should call them "areas of interest"):

Physical questions (as in natural sciences): we rely on material entities and causality.
Moral judgment: Since most people agree with Hume's guillotine, moral judgment is usually assumed to rely on a specific set of assumptions/notions (in addition to those belonging to physical descriptions).
The mind-body problem: it relies on the same notions as physical descriptions + qualia stuff, and everybody is trying to tie qualias to physicality in some way.
Decision making: when thinking about the best action to take in a given situation, we usually use a model of the situation that relies on a materialistic/causal view (for the purpose of predicting the outcome of our actions), with at least one agent involved (us). This agent choices are assumed to be (partly) free from causality (even if we do not believe in free will, we must do as if several choices are possible when deliberating).

It seems to me that several mind-twisting problems of philosophy could be explained by recognizing that some of the notions I listed are incompatible. I have only two examples in mind right now, but they are important ones, in my opinion:

the Newcomb paradox pushes the basic assumptions of decision-making to their limits: there is a clash between the assumed agency of the decision maker and the assumption that she belongs to the physical world and that her choice is hence predictible (agency vs causality).
the mind-body problem: all answers I have heard of do not stand up to analysis (in my opinion).

So there could be several possible stances: either "all models are false", or there is some hierarchy to establish between notions (in fact, some people answer to the mind-body problem by stating that either qualia or matter do not exist (eliminativist physicalists and solipsists, respectively), same for moral judgment: many people hold the view that morality is not objective).
Does this sound like something written by trained philosopher? Do you know authors that wrote about similar ideas? Especially about the incompatibilty of notions and there consequences?

you're probably thinking of some sort of logical pluralism, as in 'different contexts require different (possibly incompatible) logics'

This is loosely reminiscent of late Wittgenstein's idea, shared by other Oxford philosophers, that many problems of philosophy come from pushing words out of the "language games" they belong to that give them meaning. Wittgenstein suggested his "philosophical therapy" as a remedy for exposing and dissolving those problems. However, that some notions are incompatible is often well-recognized. Mind-twisting debates do not thereby end because they are about which ones are 'right' for the purpose.

Thank you for your answers; I'm not thinking of logical pluralism, the contradictions I'm thinking about arise because of incompatible assumptions, not different logics.

I agree that there is something common with wittgenstein's view: in both cases it suggests that language (even thoughts in my case) cannot reach some metaphysical definitive truth. I doubt that it is what I'm searching for but I will definitely search in that direction.
@JulioDiEgidio can you elaborate?

@NotDjijkjkkstra  I don't think Wittgenstein supports your views, see e.g. here for some overview: The New Wittgenstein - WP.  --  With all due respect, I just find your question overall misguided: philosophy is not logic, it is neither about formalizing things, nor it is about just following the logical dictum.

Can you be more precise in your question? What is the incompatibility in the Newcombe paradox according to you? Which notions here are incompatible? (I've studied game theory and don't see any incompatibilities in the Newscombe scenario; the paradox just seems to be muddling up totally different games - a one shot game, and the repeated game or a meta-game - and presenting them as if it was all the same game.)

What do you mean by incompatible assumptions? I studied law thirty years ago, and I studied electrical engineering prior to the study of law. In engineering studies one describes the structure and function of devices. This incorporates physics, in which one describes the geometry and properties of materials. Moral reasoning is required to be competent, ethical, professional, and to foresee outcomes of events that have social consequences. In law the cause of an event is either a moral agent or Act of God, meaning a natural event.  Incompatible distinctions arise apriori w/o prior assumptions!

I once saw something on model conflict in Domain-Dependent Cognition but can't turn it up. Perhaps Psychology.SE knows about it.

(1) Doesn't all of philosophy consist of or, at least, involve trying to answer conceptual riddles, by trying to resolve paradoxes, trying to disentangle the conceptual knots?
Are there philosophers who have written about the incompatibility of basic notions and their consequences? Isn't that what all philosophers have written about?
You refer to "incompatible basic notions". That phrase seems rather mysterious:

Does "basic" mean all humans have those notions?
If all humans are presumed to have those notions, then is that presumption an empirical claim? Or was it discovered by some kind of conceptual analysis of scientific discourse or human thinking? Do humans "necessarily" have those notions?
Does "basic" imply that when we use those notions, we cannot, as it were, escape them? Does it mean we cannot but use them? Does this also imply that we cannot further analyze them? Do they indicate some inherent, fundamental limitation in our thinking? Is their meaning somehow atomic - intuitively given? - or inexpressible?
If we have "basic notions", would we be able to demonstrate a clear incompatibility between them? Or does "basic" imply that trying to do so can only fail? If some notions are "truly basic", wouldn't we have to reduce it to "more basic" notions, in order to show an incompatibility?

If "basic notion" merely refers to words or phrases that happen to be widely used in philosophical discourse, then, I think the answer is that all philosophers have tried to resolve puzzles, riddles, paradoxes (problems that mostly seem to have some kind of conceptual nature).
(2) The Newcomb problem
This is indeed a tricky and elegant problem, but it is possible to completely analyze it in game-theoretic terms and resolve the paradox. The reasoning that concludes that as rational (utility maximizing) player one should select both boxes is only valid in the simple game (the game one plays if one doesn't know anything about the predictor/manipulator who determines what is in box B). The crux is that that simple game is a different game from the complex game, the game as presented, where the player knows about the predictor/manipulator and thus knows how the outcome actually comes to be. In the complex game, the only rational choice is to select the one box that might contain either $M or $0. In the complex game that choice conforms both to the principle of dominance and the principle of expected utility.
The upshot is that, imo, the problem is not of very great philosophical interest - at least not in sofar that it clarifies much or anything about free agency or causality. The muddle of the two reasonings that appear to be equally valid but lead to conflicting conclusions is somewhat relevant, since it suggests that philosophical puzzles can be due to misleading verbal presentations, where we seem to be dazzled by certain phrases (like "fixed and determined", "before the fact") that make us ignore (or not see or understand) that meanwhile we've changed the context, changed the rules of the game.
You might argue that surely it also says something about causality or that it involves some notion of predictibility or determinism. But the point is that we don't need any kind of special deep beliefs about what predictions are or what freedom is or causality, and all that, in order to play this game (and make the rational choice). We can use our everyday, shallow, undefined notions. The complex game can also be implemented in software and doesn't require the automated agents to have any very deep reasoning capabilities, or be AGI agents.
Looked at from the other side, I would also say that we don't learn anything new or deep about (for instance) predictability or freedom, when we resolve the paradox by pointing at the misleading representation in the reasoning (the reasoning that claims one should select both boxes).
(3) I didn't know of Newcomb's problem, and wasn't really aware of the literature around it, so I'd like to thank you for drawing attention to it. It is interesting that several philosophers still seem muddled by it. (Or perhaps, I'm the one?) But then, the debates among philosophers are endless...
UPDATE
After writing my initial response, I found some secondary literature about the Newcombe problem:

Marion Ledwig, Newcomb's Problem PhD dissertation, 2000, giving a pretty comprehensive overview of various approaches
Wolpert, Benford, The Lessons of Newcomb's paradox (2011),
claiming that the paradox arises from two different interpretations of the game scenario; two different ways of applying conditional probabilities

A short and clear, correct resolution of the "paradox" by Niel de Beaudrap, can also be found in this earlier post:

Is there a solution to Newcomb's problem?

Wolpert and Benfords's analysis comes close to a good solution, but is not correct. (In the end, they fail to show that the problem is ill-posed.) I believe this can be shown formally by applying a simpler, non-probabilistic game-theoretic approach, using Nigel Howard's theory of meta-games. The paradox can then be shown to arise from the fact that in the first-order meta-game of a simpler game the rational, dominant strategy (the strategy "choose two boxes no matter what the prediction is" which reduces to the strategy "choose two boxes" in the basic game) is rather unrealistic unless the predictors reliability or accuracy is exactly 0.5. (It's unrealistic since it assumes the belief that the predictor is simultaneously reliable and unreliable. Note that it's not impossible that this would be the case, even though we usually would not assume it to be. But there is no logical self-contradiction if you'd assume this!) When the predictor's accuracy is generally high, and the player believes this, then, after eliminating the unrealistic strategies, the new dominant strategy is to mostly (with high probability) choose the one box, and to sometimes choose both boxes (hoping against hope that in that run the predictor made an error or there was some other glitch).
So, I claim that

The game scenario as presented is not ill-posed, but perfectly understandable and consistent.
However, the game is best understood as the first-order meta-game of a particular simpler game (that doesn't involve dependencies between the players' choices).
In this meta-game the main player's belief about the accuracy/reliability of the predictor is relevant. It's obvious that  if the predictor makes random predictions, then the strategy to always choose two boxes is the rational one. And if the player knows that the predictor always happens to make correct predictions (for instance, because the predictor is always cheating), then it's just as obvious, that always choosing the one opaque box is the only rational (utility maximizing) choice.
Causality doesn't directly play a role, except in sofar it would be presupposed by the player's beliefs about the predictors accuracy. But we (and the player) can also imagine a purely probabilistic predictor. Anyway, if the player knows the actual accuracy of the predictor, then assumptions about causality are not relevant. It doesn't matter why the predictor is believed to be more or less accurate.
Conditional reasoning and bargaining in N-person games do not (need to) rely on causal assumptions, but we easily get confused becuase in many every-day contexts we do make causal assumptions, and we express conditional reasoning in terms extremely similar to expressing causal chains: "If I do this, then he will do that ..."
So, we may guess that common language patterns are now leading us astray...
The "paradox" arises due to the fact (1) that people don't see that we're dealing with two very different games, a simple basic game and  the first meta-game of this simple game (the scenario as presented by Nozick is that meta-game) and (2) that in the meta-game the dominant strategy is unrealistic (with the one exception I mentioned). There is no conflict between two principles of rationality (dominance and expected utility).


Looking closer at Nozick's article, I agree that it's not enough to explain why one or the other strategy is the maximizing "rational" one. You also want to explain what exactly is wrong with the other reasoning. It's not trivial to pin this down; it's not trivial to see what is actually relevant here (N. doesn't make this much easier). I don't have a good account for that.  My guess at the moment is that the main problem may be just plain old verbal ambiguity (of how "expected", "expectation" is used).

(Self-)reflexivity may make the problem confusing to people. But is a red herring imo.


So as a paradox of rationality, this problem (in its presentation by Nozick) is interesting as a very particular, small testcase in which we can try to pinpoint exactly where some people "go wrong in their thinking", or why people get confused about a conceptual issue. Verbal ambiguity (unacknowledged context switching) or ambiguity plus vagueness seem the most likely culprits - as always.

The muddle is not just caused by unacknowledged ambiguity (of how "expect" is interpreted), but also (related to that unobserved ambiguity) by the introduction of irrelevant notions like "influence", temporal sequencing, "cause" in the analysis of the reasoning. Those notions need not (and therefore should not) be used to justify the rational choice (at least not like Nozick is using them). If they are used, then you will likely confuse yourself - just like Nozick is confusing himself and probably some readers...

Basic means "fundamental" here. Not fundamental for all humans, but for W.E.I.R.D ones (not even for all of them, I would say, people like you and me, that know a bit of analytical philosophy, logic, maybe game theory, and have a quite materialistic view of the world).
About the Newcomb's paradox, I think that you simply underestimate the problem (like I did when I first encountered it, and like most people do, as Nozick witnesses).

By the way, if your solution is to get rid of things like "causality" to clarity the problem in terms of expected outcomes, then your solution does not contradict my view on the newcomb's paradox (I think that the paradox stems from a clash between a model of the world based on causality, and the idea that the agent has to "make a choice"; usually in decision making we assume that the world is (to some extent) deterministic and that the agent interacts with it "from outside". The newcomb paradox forces you to see the agent as a part of the deterministic world, hence the clash).

@NotDjijkjkkstra - I agree I have not proven my assertions. I'm considering writing a blog post about it. Imo "causality" (notions of causality) is irrelevant to the solution; so, it only plays a role in the incorrect reasoning.  I'm taking another look first though at a comprehensive overview in Marion Ledwig dissertation (https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/server/api/core/bitstreams/2679eac5-b306-4b65-8b91-f6702e1534a4/content) (2000) I also like to look first again as Judea Pearl's writings which might also help clarify why people think causation is involved.

@NotDjijkjkkstra - Btw I don't think I underestimate the problem as such. What I did not anticipate is how much literature (decision theory etc) + controversies it triggered. But I do admit that explaining why one solution is better than another is not as trivial as I first thought. -- Also really want to thank you for bringing this problem up. I should have learned about this much earlier, but I did not read much Western current philosophy for about 25 years, focussing only on ML.

In an earlier post https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51010/why-does-newcombs-paradox-seem-to-have-different-solutions-depending-on-when-th/51028#51028 @Conifold referred to an article by Wolpert and Benford
which contains a resolution of the paradox that is almost equivalent to the one I also had in mind - though I don't totally agree with their statement that the problem is ill-posed. Imo a simpler, purely gametheoretic, non-probabilistic approach can show the problem is not necessarily ill-posed, but the two "reasonings" do correspond to two different (unmergable) games.

@NotDjijkjkkstra My claim in the post that in the game (as presented by Nozick/Wolpert) the only rational strategy is to choose the one box, is not entirely correct. The rational strategy is a mixed strategy that depends on how accurate the predictor is. (If you don't know this, then the uncertainty about this can also be taken account of.) The paradox is not a paradox of rationality but arises from the fact that the dominant strategy in the meta-game is unrealistic (cannot be consistently believed unless the predictor has accuracy = 0.5). (Using Nigel Howard's theory of meta-games.)

Thanks for all the references! Wolpert and Benford do a nice probabilistic analysis. I do not know about Nigel Howard's meta-games, but I do not see how using game-theoretic interpretations could really solve the paradox. Supposing that you find an optimal strategy using some theory, you would then have to show that this theory can model perfectly the newcomb's paradox.

@NotDjijkjkkstra - I think it does model the scenario (with only very shallow assumptions about reality). See Nigel Howard, "Paradoxes of Rationality: Games, Metagames, and Political Behavior" (1971) His theoretic framework is a little different from earlier game-theory, but compatible afaik.

If the philosophy you adhere to has subtly incompatible assumptions when approaching these problems (physical questions, moral judgment, the mind-body problem, decision making, the Newcomb paradox), then your philosophy is subtly wrong and needs revision.
Reasoning is the pursuit of a simple set of assumptions that produce consequences that cohere with each other and explain observations.
I'll tell you how I approach these problems in a unified way. Essentially I say that everything is a physical question, and all the problems can be answered from that perspective.

Physical questions: whatever exists in the universe obeys the laws of physics, that say when one event shall follow another. A physical question can ask about what is - how many pounds of flour are in the pantry? Or it can ask about what would be, under hypothetical circumstances. If we set this iron ball bouncing on this steel surface, how many bounces would it take to come to a rest? If we built a bridge according to these plans, how heavy a truck could drive over it before it collapsed? If this computer followed this algorithm forever, would it ever reach line 75?
The mind-body problem: the laws of physics are also laws of the mind, that say when one "thought" (mental event) shall follow another. There is only one substance, which we may call physical or mental, and even in its simplest forms this substance has the nature of subjective qualia. This perspective, called panpsychism, is simpler and more unified than the dualist perspective; instead of needing two kinds of fundamental thing in the universe, we can say there is only one.
Decision making: there is no need to talk about free will or make any special assumptions; we can simply use hypothetical reasoning, as we must do to answer any physical question. If a person decided to throw his computer in the river, would he regret the decision afterwards? This is no different in character from asking whether, if an 1cm iron ball were set bouncing on a steel surface, it would take less than or greater than 100 bounces to come to rest.
Moral judgment: I interpret moral questions as questions about what a person would prefer to do, if they were hypothetically allowed unlimited time to think and access to unlimited factual evidence and moral arguments. The person's mind is a system, of which we may form an idealized model (as we must do when analyzing any physical question). What belief state or moral preference state the system would eventually settle on is a potentially well-defined question, just like the question of whether a Turing machine will halt or how many times a ball will bounce.
Newcomb's paradox: This is a question about what someone should do under certain circumstances. So I interpret it the same way as I interpret moral questions: what would the person end up wanting to do, if they were allowed to consider the scenario as long as necessary?


Philosophy is not logic: and your answer (IMO) is just biased and in fact an example of unphilosophical.

I'd be interested to know what you actually would do (would want to do) as player in the Newcomb scenario. (1) Do you choose (or want to choose) one box or two boxes?  (2) What do you expect/hope to get as outcome? (3) What reasoning did you apply - if you applied any reasoning - to make your choice? (Note that Nozick anticipates that a player can make a random choice. That possibility is accounted for in the scenario. See a footnote about this in the article.) You may take as much time as you want :)

@mudskipper One box. Agents that choose one box get more money, therefore I want to be an agent that chooses one box. To put it another way, if I were designing a robot to solve this problem for me, I would observe better results if I design the robot to choose one box, and so that's what I should do myself.

That's what I had predicted for you even though I've only seen very few of your behaviors - so you would indeed get the million bucks. Congratulations! It's also interesting  to see that in your reasoning about your own choices, you adopt a 3d person perspective - I think that's pretty rare :)

@mudskipper Sure, I think analyzing the human mind like we're designing a robot mind is required to have the right perspective in philosophy. Consider the following modification of Newcomb's paradox: there's a game show where you program a robot to either choose one or both boxes. After the robot is released but before it is allowed to choose, there's a game referee who scans the robot's program and puts the million dollars in the hidden box only if the program says the robot will choose one box. I don't think anyone would say you should program the robot to pick two boxes, in that scenario.

Indeed. And you can actually make this argument stronger by either applying an evolutionary algorithm to a population of robots or by letting the robots adjust their strategies after observing outcomes from both themselves and other robots. I don't know if those kind of programs have been developed for this game, but several programs and studies have been developed for instance for the ultimatum game (and of course for prisoners dilemma) which study other so-called "paradoxes of rationality".

It's actually pretty wild to see how elementary some of the mistakes are that Nozick makes in his analysis (if you are somewhat familiar with game-theory, dynamics of games and meta-games). I wonder if a mathematician has found this sufficiently interesting to take him to task.

Sure, if you program a robot to play instead of you, the best strategy is to make it chose only one box. But the problem is not "program a robot to play the game", nor "program yourself beforehand so that you can win the game", it's "You are now in front of the boxes: which one do you pick? Do you pick only one box, disregarding causality (because if you can get 1M, nothing can stop you from getting 1M + 1k now)? Or do you pick both boxes, knowing that you will lose?".

@NotDjijkjkkstra But you are "programming yourself beforehand so you can win the game." "Programming yourself" in this instance is called "making a plan for what to do." You would rather make a plan that nets you $1 million than a plan that nets you $1 thousand. And that's the plan to take one box.

@NotDjijkjkkstra - A robot need not be designed to make that particular choice in advance! (1) We can either use an evolutionary program with a population of robots and let them develop and discover strategies. Or (2) We can codify the conditional reasoning itself - since it is so extremely simple - and program a robot that is able to switch between games and first-order meta-games, and let it come to its own conclusions.

(3) In an evolutionary approach we could also first let a population evolve that is (by evolution) trained to solve Newtonlike problems (so leave out this particular problem). Then after a while, run a 1-shot version of this particular problem in this population.

I agree with what you both said but, again, Newcomb's paradox is not about "what kind of agent would win", or "what plan should you decide before the game starts". It's "what should you do when you're in front of the boxes" (by the way, supposing that you had devised a plan, it would not really changes your situation because nothing forces you to stick to the plan at the moment of choosing).

@NotDjijkjkkstra Well, when we are now deciding "what should you do when you're in front of the boxes," this is making a plan. And we're (both) doing it before the game starts. It's true that if you actually get in front of the boxes, you might change the plan. If you do, you will get less money than someone who stuck to the plan. So you should stick to the plan and not change it.
